# What Chinese language(s) have pronunciation ㄍ丨(romanization: gi)

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

Heard pronunciation ㄍ丨(romanization: gi) recently in a dialect of south western mandarin.

I was trying to trace it together with something else.

[Seems like](http://www.slideserve.com/oona/3438032) Hakka pronounces 机/機 ㄍ丨but I couldn't really see much else.

What Chinese language(s) have pronunciation ㄍ丨(romanization: gi)?

Comment: According to (wikipedia)[https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E6%97%8F], At leaset some variants of 吴语, 赣语, and 客家语 uses `gi` as a third person singular pronoun.

Comment: Wiki does say of MSM: there is neither *[ki] nor *[kɨ]

Comment: What is ㄍ here? Certainly not the ㄍ in 注音符號, for there it doesn't pronounce as gi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 机 is pronounced *gi*(pin yin) in Hakka. But not all "Ji" pronunciations have the same reflection. e.g. 鸡 is pronounced *gie*(pin yin) in Hakka, not *gi*.

Other examples I remember for now: 几，吉，记，季，寄，继，计，贵， etc. Of course, they have different tones.

Comment: I think / / represents IPA so it should be written /ki/ not /gi/

Comment: @user3306356 thanks for your correction.